# Invoke a method on an arbitrary thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a scenario where I have a main thread which uses a whole bunch of other threads from the threadpool that do some work.

In the main thread I am using an object which is not thread safe (3rd party component, so it's not feasible to change this). The threadpool threads need to invoke methods on this non-thread-safe object. In the main thread I have an object representing the thread on which the 3rd party component is declared:

```
private ThirdPartyComponent third_party_component;
private Thread mainThread;
```

In the initialization method on the main thread, I save a reference to the "safe" thread for accessing the 3rd party component:

```
mainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
```

What I am trying to do is create some method which will "dispatch" the invocation of the 3rd party component to the correct thread, something like this:

```
private void DoTheWork()
{
    if(Thread.CurrentThread != mainThread)
    {
         mainThread.Invoke( () => { third_party_component.DoItThreadSafe(); } );
    }
}
```

I have regularly used this pattern for updating UI code on the main thread using `Control.Invoke`, but the `Thread` object which I have saved (`mainThread`) does not have an `Invoke` method.

Is there something special about the UI thread that allows this to take place? Or am I missing something on the `Thread` object? What is the best way to get `DoTheWork()` to run on the main thread?

(Edit: FWIW in this application `mainThread` will be the main Winforms GUI thread, but I am hoping to find a solution which works on any thread and does not rely on the main thread being the GUI thread.)

Comment: At most you can create a new thread to run the code on, but you cannot (safely) inject code on another thread. Instead, you should have some form of communication mechanism where you can make the thread that owns the central object here look at this communication mechanism and pick up "work to be done". Basically, you have to reverse your thinking on this, don't force work upon a thread, instead make that thread go and get work itself.

Comment: The reason you can send stuff to the GUI thread is because it's running a *message loop* to pick up work to do. Those messages can be events from the window manager but can also be requests from other threads to invoke a delegate.

Comment: [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) -> [Current](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current) -> [Post()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post). -- [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext). `BeginInvoke()` works just fine, though.

Comment: The requirement you are trying to implement indicates that the third-party-component not only isn't thread-safe, but it also requires [thread affinity](http://www.volatileread.com/Thread/index?id=1056). This is a requirement usually associated with UI components. Are you sure that it is really required in your case? If not, a simple [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) should be sufficient for accessing the component safely.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Single Thread Apartment (STA) COM components aslo require thread affinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when talking about non-threadsafe objects it simply means it cannot be called by multiple threads concurrently. If so it should be safe to simply lock the non-threadsafe object and call it from whatever thread you are using.

It is possible to write objects that can only be called by the thread that created the object thread. If so perhaps something like this could work:

```
public class TaskManager<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> constructor;
    private BlockingCollection<Action<T>> queue = new BlockingCollection<Action<T>>(new ConcurrentQueue<Action<T>>());

    public TaskManager(Func<T> constructor)
    {
        this.constructor = constructor;
        var thread = new Thread(ThreadMain);
        thread.Start();
    }

    private void ThreadMain()
    {
        var obj = constructor();
        foreach(var action in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            action(obj);
        }
    }

    public void ScheduleWork(Action<T> work) => queue.Add(work);
    public void CompleteAdding() => queue.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Disclaimer: Not tested, no error handling, no handling of disposable objects etc.

Comment: Combining `IsCompleted` with `Take` should generally be avoided because it introduces race conditions. The safe and easy way to keep-taking-until-completed is to enumerate the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable).